# creating an HTML file with ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I'm currently creating a report page in HTML format with ruby

An Example is:

```
fileHtml = File.new("filename.html", "w+")

fileHtml.puts "<HTML>"
fileHtml.puts "<HEAD>"
fileHtml.puts "<style media='all' type='text/css'>"
fileHtml.puts "body {font-family: Helvetica Neue, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #525252; padding: 0; margin: 0;background: #f2f2f2;}"
fileHtml.puts ".content {max-width:1180px; padding: 40px;}"
fileHtml.puts ".div1 {margin-top: 28px; margin-bottom: 1px; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px 40px; padding-bottom: 8px; }"
fileHtml.puts ".div2 {margin-top: 2px; height:25%; margin-bottom: 28px; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px 40px; padding-bottom: 8px; }"
fileHtml.puts ".header {background-color: white; height: 16%; min-height: 110px; position: relative; width: 100%; -webkit-user-select: none;}"
fileHtml.puts ".secondSection {background-color: #e8e8e8; height: 16%; min-height: 110px; position: relative; width: 100%; -webkit-user-select: none;}"
fileHtml.puts ".pass {color: #ffffff; background: #34d9a2; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; width:50px;}"
fileHtml.puts ".fail {color: #ffffff; background: #f25e6a; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; width:50px;}"
fileHtml.puts "</style>"
fileHtml.puts "</HEAD>"
fileHtml.puts "<BODY>"
fileHtml.puts "<DIV class='header'><img src='img.png' alt='logo'></div>"
fileHtml.puts "<DIV class='secondSection'><p>#{dateTime}</p><p>#{platform}</p><p>#{log}</p></div>"
fileHtml.puts "<DIV class='content'>"
fileHtml.puts "<DIV class='div1'><h2>Test Case 001: name</h2></DIV>"
fileHtml.puts "<DIV class='div2'><p class='pass'>#{pass}</p><p class='fail'>#{fail}</p></DIV>"
fileHtml.puts "</DIV>"
fileHtml.puts "</BODY></HTML>"

fileHtml.close()
```

Was wondering if i'm approaching this incorrectly and if there was another way to create HTML files and insert stored variable results

Comment: Go through the following

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796459/what-gem-can-i-use-to-generate-a-html-file-for-offline-use

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you mean is called [embedded Ruby or ERB for short](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html). You can save your template as a separate file, for example `template.erb`. Then you can render the content in your ruby script with simple tags, for example `<%= @var %>`. You can pass the `binding` to ERB, that way you will be able to access instance variables (the ones with an `@` at the beginning) inside your `template.html.erb`:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <!-- etc... -->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <DIV class='header'><img src='img.png' alt='logo'></div>
  <DIV class='secondSection'>
    <p><%= @date_time %></p>
    <p><%= @platform %></p>
    <p><%= @log %></p>
  </div>
  <DIV class='content'>
  <DIV class='div1'>
    <h2>Test Case 001: name</h2>
  </DIV>
  <DIV class='div2'>
    <p class='pass'><%= @pass %></p>
    <p class='fail'><%= @fail %></p>
  </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Then, in your program:

```
# do computation and set your instance variables
@date_time = ...
@platform  = ...
@log       = ...
@pass      = ...
@fail      = ...

# render template
template = File.read('./template.html.erb')
result = ERB.new(template).result(binding)

# write result to file
File.open('filename.html', 'w+') do |f|
  f.write result
end

# file is closed automatically with File.open do ... end
```

You can even do more advanced stuff like loops inside the template:

```
<% [1,2,3].each do |number| %>
  <%= number %>
<% end %>
```

notice the difference between `<% ... %>`, which will only run the code, and `<%= ... %>`, which will take the return value and "write" its string representation into the template.

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed - not one, but many. One simple one is to use heredoc string format:

```
string = <<-EOF
<HTML>
<HEAD>
... #{pass} ....
</HTML>
EOF
```

Another is using a templating engine. One is already baked into Ruby core library: [ERb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html).

For even more abstraction, you could look into Haml and Sass gems, or Slim.

Answer (score 0):

How about using heredoc?

```
fileHtml = File.new("filename.html", "w+")

fileHtml.write <<EOH
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<style media='all' type='text/css'>
body {font-family: Helvetica Neue, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #525252; padding: 0; margin: 0;background: #f2f2f2;}
.content {max-width:1180px; padding: 40px;}
.div1 {margin-top: 28px; margin-bottom: 1px; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px 40px; padding-bottom: 8px; }
.div2 {margin-top: 2px; height:25%; margin-bottom: 28px; background-color: #fff; padding: 10px 40px; padding-bottom: 8px; }
.header {background-color: white; height: 16%; min-height: 110px; position: relative; width: 100%; -webkit-user-select: none;}
.secondSection {background-color: #e8e8e8; height: 16%; min-height: 110px; position: relative; width: 100%; -webkit-user-select: none;}
.pass {color: #ffffff; background: #34d9a2; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; width:50px;}
.fail {color: #ffffff; background: #f25e6a; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; text-decoration: none; width:50px;}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class='header'><img src='img.png' alt='logo'></div>
<DIV class='secondSection'><p>#{dateTime}</p><p>#{platform}</p><p>#{log}</p></div>
<DIV class='content'>
<DIV class='div1'><h2>Test Case 001: name</h2></DIV>
<DIV class='div2'><p class='pass'>#{pass}</p><p class='fail'>#{fail}</p></DIV>
</DIV>
</BODY></HTML>
EOH

fileHtml.close()
```